# Rename executable for single script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to run shell script, where `exe1` instead being looked up as `/path/to/exe1` instead references what I see as `exe2` in `/path/to/exe2`. Ideally, I want to do this in the most compact way with minimal side effects.

To make this example concrete, and somewhat similar to the problem I actually care about, I have a shell script `script.sh` where

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python --version
```

I have two executables on my current `PATH`:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.x
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.x
```

I want to call `script.sh` in such a way that

```
$ <magic> ./script.sh
Python 3.5.x
$ python --version
Python 2.7.x
```

The best solution I can find so far is

```
$ mkdir /tmp/python3 && ln -s $(which python3) /tmp/python3/python && env PATH="/tmp/python3:$PATH" ./script.sh
```

This could be made a little better by using `mktemp -d` and cleaning up, but it still involves writing mostly unnecessary files, for something it seems like I should just be able to tell bash, treat python as python3. Something like aliases would be ideal, but they don't get passed onto subshells. Is there an obvious tool I'm missing, or am I stuck with a variant of this method?

Comment: So you want to run the script and, based on something you did outside the script, be able to have it access which ever version of python you want at that moment?  That is, "today I want Python 3, so doas3 ./script.sh"?  would it be acceptable to run your script with a parameter and have it determine what to run?  That is, "./script.sh -p 3" and then the script says something like "if -p 3, use python3, else python2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call script.sh in such a way that

```
$ <magic> ./script.sh
Python 3.5.x
$ python --version
Python 2.7.x
```

---

You can do it like this using a function:

```
(python() { python3 "$@"; }; declare -xf python; ./script.sh)
```

- We create a function called `python` inside a subshell that just invokes `python3` executable.
- Doing it in a sub-shell so that current environment is not messed up.